# Intermidiate "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-s3

I am getting an intermediate "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream" errors on my server.
The error only occurs on the data that is requested throe the server from Amazon S3 and not on any of the files from the server itself.

My setup is as following:

1 Load balancer that is based on Nginx nginx version: nginx/1.11.5 (Out of Ubuntu repository)

It's configuration is:

```
server {

    server_name  example.com

    client_body_timeout 12s;
    client_header_timeout 12s;
    keepalive_timeout 15s;

    access_log off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1000s;
    proxy_send_timeout 1000s;
    proxy_read_timeout 1000s;
    send_timeout 1000s;

    location / {
            set $ua $http_user_agent;

            if ($http_user_agent = "")
            {
                    set           $ua "Fixing-Empty-User-Agent";
            }


            proxy_pass http://front_least;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
            proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding "";
    }
}

    upstream front_least {
    least_conn;
    server localF1.example.com;
    server localF2.example.com;
    server f1.example.com backup; # Public ports
    server f2.example.com backup; # Public ports
    keepalive 32;
}
```

2. 2 Front servers that have Nginx on them. The configuration between them is exactly the same, and I will show only partial config here, the full one is too big.

The F configuration (The relevant part IMHO):

```
# Fix S3 Content Type error
    map $uri $custom_content_type {
            default "binary/octet-stream";
            ~(.*\.png)$ "image/png";
            ~(.*\.jpg)$ "image/jpeg";
            ~(.*\.jpeg)$ "image/jpeg";
            ~(.*\.gif)$ "image/gif";
            ~(.*\.ico)$ "image/x-icon";
    }

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com *.example.com;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml+rss;
    gzip_vary on;

    pagespeed on;

    ...
    Huje amount of lines related to pagespeed
    ...

   location /gallery/ {
        try_files $uri @s3icons;
    }
    location /gallery_thumbnails/ {
        try_files $uri @s3icons;
    }
    location /icon/ {
        try_files $uri @s3icons;
    }
    location /screenshot/ {
        try_files $uri @s3icons;
    }
    location /vendor/ {
        try_files $uri @s3icons;
    }

    location @s3icons {

            proxy_set_header       Host 'bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com';
            proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
            add_header Content-Type $custom_content_type;

            proxy_http_version     1.1;
            proxy_set_header       Connection "";
            proxy_pass http://s3_icons;

    }

    include common/error.conf;
    include common/deny.conf;
}


    # Define a mapping used to mark HTML as uncacheable.
      map $upstream_http_content_type $new_cache_control_header_val {
        default $upstream_http_cache_control;
        "~*text/html" "no-cache, max-age=0";
      }

upstream s3_images {
    server bucket_1.s3.amazonaws.com;
    keepalive 10;
}

upstream s3_icons {
    server bucket_2.s3.amazonaws.com;
    keepalive 10;
}
```

Now, I am only getting the error on images coming from S3, if I point the from from the load ballancer to the Front servers, there is no error.
If I check the same file that is in the log in Curl or the browser I am getting the image without a problem.
But the logs show that there is a problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for `keepalive 10;`?

Comment: It's from the manuals, I have to have keepalive between them for it to work.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive

Comment: Enter send the message - The keepalive is not the timeout, it's the number of IDLE connection that are kept by the system.

Comment: That's probably too many connections, because S3 will close a connection that is idle for very long.  I would drop this to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried it, and it did not worked...

Comment: In the end, I have created a cloudfront distribution that works with behaivoar and serves the files per directory.